# FileInputStream - how to take a path directly, without adding escape characters?

Tags: java

I have a file path C:\games\file.txt
To pass this to a FileInputStream constructor, we have to do

```
FileInputStream("C:\\games\\file.txt");
```

Is there any way I can construct a file path without using these extra \ or escape characters ?

I also want this code to be platform independent.

Comment: File paths are inherently platform dependent. Your best bet is probably to store file paths (or at least a base path) in an external resource like a property file.

Comment: Use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` to obtain the underlying platform's file separator string.

Comment: Of course "C:" is a dead give-away. Use `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/games/file.txt"`.

Comment: @JoopEggen - but wont / fail for windows ? I think you're working on a linux system.

Comment: @SuperStar I remember reading somewhere that java managed the change from / to \ on windows.

Comment: @SuperStar the case is that Windows in the beginning wanted to distinguish itsef from Unix and chose `\` i.o. `/`. Nevertheless also the Posix standard was maintained with many Standard C functions. And [slash](http://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes) in many cases possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [File.separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) for that or `/`.

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"games"+
              File.separator+"file.txt";
```